# Solving an integral using differentiation under the integral sign

Tags: calculus, integration, leibniz-integral-rule

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \exp\Big(-x^2-\frac{a^2}{x^2}\Big)\,\mathrm dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2e^{-2|a|}$$

How do we prove the above result? I tried using the Leibniz Integral rule but I ended up getting an indefinite answer because of the $x^2$ in the denominator in the power.

Answer (score 5):

You have only requested for a solution using differentiation under the integral sign, but I've two solutions. I'll be sharing both of them.

**Using differentiation under the integral sign:**

For $a\ge 0$, let
$$I(a) = \int\limits_0^\infty\exp\Big(-x^2-\frac{a^2}{x^2}\Big)\,\mathrm dx$$

Differentiating both sides w.r.t. $a$, we get
$$I'(a) = -2\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{a}{x^2}\exp\Big(-x^2-\frac{a^2}{x^2}\Big) \,\mathrm dx$$

Substituting $x\mapsto\frac ax$, we get

$$I'(a) = -2 \int\limits_0^\infty\exp\Big(-x^2-\frac{a^2}{x^2}\Big)\,\mathrm dx = -2I(a) $$
The general solution for this differential equation will be $I(a) =k_1 e^{-2a}$. Noting that $I(0) = \frac{\sqrt\pi}2$, we get $k_1 = \frac{\sqrt\pi}2$. Thus, for $a\geq0$
$$ \int\limits_0^\infty\exp\Big(-x^2-\frac{a^2}{x^2}\Big)\,\mathrm dx = \frac{\sqrt\pi}2e^{-2a}$$
Putting modulus around $a$ extends the result $\forall a\in \mathbb R$.

**Using substitution:**

In the same $I(a) $, substitute $x\mapsto \frac ax$. This gives

$$I(a) = \int \limits_0^\infty\frac a{x^2} \exp\Big(-x^2-\frac {a^2}{x^2}\Big) \,\mathrm dx$$

Adding the two equations,

$$I(a) = \frac12 \int\limits_0^\infty\exp\Big(-x^2-\frac {a^2}{x^2}\Big)\Big(1+\frac a{x^2}\Big)\,\mathrm dx $$
Now, we note that $x^2+\frac{a^2}{x^2}= (x-\frac ax)^2+2a $. Keeping this in mind, we substitute $t=x-\frac ax$. This gives

$$I(a) = \frac{e^{-2a}}2 \int\limits_{-\infty} ^\infty e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt $$
The later integral is the Gaussian integral, equal to $\sqrt\pi$. After using the fact that the integrand is even, we had used this result to calculate $k_1$. Using this result, we get the same result as before.

Comment if any mistakes or confusion regarding the steps.

Comment: The question stated that the solution had the exponent under the radical sign. Was that the incorrect result?

Comment: @Gizzel I am pretty sure that the result was incorrect. I have tried some values for $a$ on Wolfram Alpha, and the result I proved works. BTW if you are satisfied, then please accept the answer.

Comment: It's all good! Thank you so much!